# MacOS Microsoft Remote Desktop - external monitors cut in half horizontally

Tags: remote-desktop

Upgraded my MacBook Pro to Ventura 13.2.1. Dual monitors connected via a thunderbolt hub. This has worked bun multiple monitor mode for the past 9 months until now (the OS upgrade). Rebooted the remote Win10 desktop and my local Mac.

Single monitor mode works fine. Both external monitors look like this and the MacBook monitor if fine. At a loss what to try next.[image]

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out by accident.  Prior to my Venture 13.2.1 update the RD app would glitch out unless the Man menu bar was on the laptop - the external monitors would get cut off on the top.

On a hunch I switched that back and now it works and the old glitch is gone.  Very weird but a win-win.